# PHP/MySQL - Sorting data starting with specific rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL table with similar data

```
France  - 1
Germany - 2
Italy   - 3
France  - 5
Germany - 3
France  - 2
```

I want to select everything (It's easy SELECT * FROM table), but I want to sort data the way that France will be always first, so outcome should be:

```
France  - 1
France  - 5
France  - 2
Germany - 2
Germany - 3
Italy   - 3
```

Can this be done on MySQL side or I should do this inside foreach statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
select * from your_table
order by country <> 'France',
         country
```

or

```
select * from your_table
order by case when country = 'France'
              then 1
              else 2
         end,
         country
```

Comment: I just found "select * from table order by field(county, 'FRANCE'), variety" this is better or...?

Comment: Whatever works for you is fine. There are acually even more possibilities to do it

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from   
   countrydata order by country ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $id=$row[0];
    $name=$row[1];
    echo $name."&nbsp;".$id."<br>";
}
```